# What does iTunes Match think a specific track is?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I have one track of an album that got matched, while the other 22 didn't; therefore, I'm sure that there must be a compilation with this track that iTunes Match knows about. How can I check which track actually got matched to?

Comment: OK, just got it using SoundHound, but nevertheless I'm still interested in this question.

Answer (score 1):

It uses "digital fingerprinting" to match the track. The exact method is secret.  I've got lots of albums where a few tracks didn't get matched.